# How is if statement evaluated in c++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, evaluation

Is `if ( c )` the same as `if ( c == 0 )` in C++?

Comment: Bear in mind that 0 doesn't always mean the same thing.  It can be the null pointer constant or integer zero.

Comment: Don't you mean "Is if ( c ) the same as if ( c != 0 ) in C++?" ?

Comment: Is the variable c of a particular type?

Comment: Just int. But what happens if c is a pointer? 'if (c)' checks if c is pointing to something?

Comment: @derrdji, it's comparing against 0, which is value zero of type int. Depending on the type of c, different things will happen. If c is an object of a class, its overloaded operator== can be called. If c is a double, then the integer will be converted to double. And if c is a pointer, then the integer will be converted to a null pointer, and the comparison against the null pointer will check whether `c` points to a valid object (or function) of its type. Note that in all cases, 0 is always the same and always means the same. It just can be converted to many different things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do negative numbers return false in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840422/do-negative-numbers-return-false-in-c-c)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

No, `if (c)` is the same as `if (c != 0)`.
And `if (!c)` is the same as `if (c == 0)`.

Comment: Assuming no odd overloading is taking place, which is often part of the answer in C++.

Comment: Ofcourse, if the operators == or != are overloaded, anything could happen, it could even start playing the national anthem for you... ;-)

Comment: One of these days I'm going to make a class which overloads operators to play sound effects. It's gonna be awesome every time someone wants to sort them.

Answer (score 25):

I'll break from the pack on this one... "`if (c)`" is closest to "`if (((bool)c) == true)`". For integer types, this means "`if (c != 0)`". As others have pointed out, overloading `operator !=` can cause some strangeness but so can overloading "`operator bool()`" unless I am mistaken.

Comment: The question was originally tagged with only C, hence the above answers since there is no bool in C.

Comment: if(static_cast<bool>(c)) ... I'll get my coat.

Comment: Or `if(bool cond = c) ...;` to show the conversion is implicit.

Answer (score 7):

If c is a pointer or a numeric value,

```
if( c )
```

is equivalent to

```
if( c != 0 )
```

If c is a boolean (type bool [only C++]),
(edit: or a user-defined type with the overload of the operator bool())

```
if( c )
```

is equivalent to

```
if( c == true )
```

If c is nor a pointer or a numeric value neither a boolean,

```
if( c )
```

will not compile.

Comment: It c is a user-defined type one can just implement `operator bool()` as D. Shawley and galets both pointed out and so it will compile just fine.

Comment: Exact, I add it to the explanation

Answer (score 3):

It's more like `if ( c != 0 )`

Of course, `!=` operator can be overloaded so it's not perfectly accurate to say that those are exactly equal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are the same if you change `== 0` to `!= 0`.

Comment: The if statement is *defined* to accept anything non-zero as true. So yes it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is only true for numeric values. if c is class, there must be an operator overloaded which does conversion boolean, such as in here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class c_type
{
public:
    operator bool()
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    c_type c;
    if (c) printf("true");
    if (!c) printf ("false");
}
```

Answer (score -5):

If `c` is a pointer then the test

```
if ( c )
```

is not quite the same as

```
if ( c != 0 )
```

The latter is a straightforward check of `c` against the `0` (null) pointer whereas the former is actually a instruction to check whether `c` is points to a valid object. Typically compilers produce the same code though.

Comment: no, it's not... both mean absolutely the same in the case of a pointer: if( c != NULL )

Comment: There is no way for the compile and/or the runtime to know whether an object is valid in either C or C++.
You can write:
"  X* c = (X*)1;  "
Then c almost certainly points to an invalid object. And
"  if(c) " will be true.

Comment: @Andrew: I doubt you can justify your statement that there is no way to check that the object is valid or not. Certainly it would require a lot of effort by the compiler to generate run-time code to check and that's why compilers don't bother and generate the same code i.e. test against the null pointer. That's why your example fails to produce a false result on (probably) all current compilers.

Comment: @Massa: I'm afraid not. My reference is section 6.3.2 (Selection Statements) from "The C++ Programming Language, Special Edition" by Bjarne Stroustrup (the creator of C++). What's yours?

Comment: Comparing an object pointer against a null pointer does check whether it points to a valid object, while "valid object" means "object with non-null-pointer address"