# Do negative numbers return false in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, boolean

When evaluating integers as booleans in C/C++, are negative numbers true or false?  Are they always true/false regardless of compilers?

Comment: Anything that is not zero is true.

Comment: As you'll see from the answers below quoting from different standards, C and C++ are not the same language.

Comment: why don't you try yourself? `if(-1) cout << "true" << endl;`

Comment: @JackCColeman: how does that make duck wrong, exactly? He says anything which is not zero is true; -1 is not zero, and so -1 is true. This appears to surprise you for some reason, but it is precisely what duck said, and also what Brendan's program says.

Comment: Everything that is not zero is true, but that doesn't mean that v == TRUE for all values of v that are not zero! Is that where this question is comming from?

Comment: @JackCColeman On a two's complement machine it is not possible to have the sign bit on and still have a zero integer value.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten What about if we're talking about the floating point -0?

Comment: ... I remember BASIC interpreter that stored "true" as -1.  I guess that's where questions like this come from.

Comment: @texasbruce His question specifically asks if negative numbers are always evaluated as true/false *regardless of compilers*. Testing it on his machine makes no guarantees. Refer him to the spec rather than ask him to test something he's not sure is compiler-dependent.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

All non-zero values will be converted to `true`, and zero values to `false`. With negative numbers being non-zero, they are converted to `true`.

Quoting from the C++11 standard (emphasis mine):

> 4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]
>
> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
>   to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. **A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`.** A prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the
>   resulting value is false.

---

> Are they always true/false regardless of compilers?

You will only get the above guarantee when your compiler is standards-compliant, or at least, complies with this specific part of the standard. In practice, all compilers have this standard behavior, so there isn't much to worry about.

Comment: Note that the question (perhaps not entirely appropriately) asks about both C and C++. The result is the same in both, but the rules are stated differently. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18863247/827263) for the gory details.

Answer (score 9):

You can test it yourself by compiling this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (-1) {
        printf("-1 is true\n");
    } else {
        printf("-1 is false\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

> $ gcc -Wall -pedantic test.c -o test-c
>   $ g++ -Wall -pedantic test.c -o test-cpp
>   $ ./test-c
>   -1 is true
>   $ ./test-cpp
>   -1 is true

Of course, to answer the second part of your question, "Are they always true/false regardless of compilers?", the only way to be completely sure is to look at the spec. In general though, compilers will warn you if you do something dangerous, and you can see from the output above, that even with "pedantic" [warnings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Warning-Options.html), `gcc` considers this code to be perfectly fine.

Comment: Being nit-picky but an example run on one or even several compilers does not prove this works or should work across all of them, i.e. that it is not implementation dependent.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That's true. I updated the answer to give some more detail, and also add `-Wall -pedantic`, to show that gcc doesn't see anything wrong with this. I created this answer after the spec ones, mainly to show that the first part of the question is easily testable.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: Negative values, and any non-zero values in general, are treated as true when used as conditions.

For C, there are a number of contexts in which an expression is treated as a condition. Conditions are not necessarily of type `bool` or `_Bool`; that type was only added to the language by the 1999 standard.

The most obvious of these contexts is the expression in an `if` statement, but there are other examples: `while`, `do-while`, the second expression in a `for` header, the first operand of the `?:` conditional operator, and the operand(s) of the `!`, `&&`, and `||` operators. (I *think* that's an exhaustive list, but I'm not certain.)

Here's what the C standard says about the behavior of the `if` statement ("both forms" refers to `if` with and without an `else` clause):

> In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0.

Which means that this:

```
if (foo) ...
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if ((foo) != 0) ...
```

(adding extra parentheses to avoid any operator precedence issues). The meaning is clear if `foo` is of type `int`. If `foo` is of some floating-point type, `0` is converted to the same type (which can cause some subtleties if the value happens to be a negative zero or a NaN). And if `foo` is a pointer, `0` is treated as a null pointer constant; `if (ptr)` is equivalent to `if (ptr != NULL)` (assuming the definition of `NULL` is visible).

For C++, the rules are stated a bit differently, but the effect is the same. The condition in a C++ `if` statement is converted to type `bool` (unlike in C, the type `bool` has been built into C++ since its early history). The conversion of a value of any scalar type to `bool` is defined by the C++ standard as:

> A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is
> converted to **false**; any other value is converted to true. A
> prvalue of type **std::nullptr_t** can be converted to a prvalue of
> type **bool**; the resulting value is **false**.

So in both C and C++, any scalar (i.e., integer, floating-point, or pointer) value can be used as a condition, and the condition is false if the scalar is equal to zero, and true if it's not equal to zero. C defines this as an inequality comparison to `0`. C++ defines it as a conversion to `bool` -- but the result is the same.

This is getting a bit off the topic of the question, but it's important to note that a value that is treated as a true condition is not necessarily *equal* to `true`. `true` (which is `1` in C if you have `#include <stdbool.h>`, and a unique value of type `bool` in C++) is just one of many values that possess "truthiness" when used in a condition. Which is why you should almost never write:

```
if (cond == true) ...
```

in either C or C++ (unless you really need to compare it to that one value); just write:

```
if (cond) ...
```

A C++ example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int n = 2;
    if (n)         std::cout << "n has truthiness\n";
    else           std::cout << "n does not have truthiness\n";
    if (n == true) std::cout << "n == true\n";
    else           std::cout << "n != true\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
n has truthiness
n != true
```

(C also has built-in complex types. A complex value is treated as true unless both its real and imaginary parts are equal to zero.)

(The upcoming 2023 edition of the C standard will have `bool` as a built-in type, and `false` and `true` as keywords.)

Answer (score 3):

Anything that is not `0` will be converted to `true`(*1 in the case of C*) a `zero` value will be converted to `false`(*0 in the case of C*). With respect to *C* if we look at the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.3.1.2` *Boolean type* paragraph *1* says:

> When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal
>   to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

For completeness sake if we look at section `7.16` *Boolean type and values*  paragraph *2* says:

```
The macro 

 bool

expands to _Bool.
```

with respect to *C++* the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) in section `4.12` *Boolean conversions* paragraph *1* says(*emphasis mine*):

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. **A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to true.**[...]

This should hold regardless of which compiler you use.

Answer (score -3):

Good question.  The answer is "depends".

```
if (-1) { // this is always true
}
```

On the other hand, suppose you are on a 16 bit machine:

```
if (-65536) { // this is always false
}
```

On the other hand,

```
int a = whatever doesn't matter;
if (a < 0) { // this might or might not be true
    if (a) { // this will always be true if we get here
    }
}
```

So negative numbers are not always false, except sometimes they always are.

Comment: In standard C (99 or 11, at least), LONG_MIN must be less than or equal to -2147483647, and decimal integer constants are given the first type of `int`, `long int`, `long long int` which can represent the number. Consequently, `-65536` will be either `int` or `long int`, and in any case negative. So regardless of the bitness of the machine, `if (-65536) do_it();` will always `do_it()`. Had you assigned `-65536` (or, for that matter, `65536`) to `uint16_t a`, then `if (a) do_it();` probably wouldn't `do_it()`, but `a` probably wouldn't be negative (UB, though).

Comment: On a 16 bit microcontroller, int and long int are probably both going to be 16 bits, in which case -65536 will be stored as the literal zero, *maybe* with a compiler warning, but it will still be zero.

Comment: @danielV: if long int is 16  bits, then what you have is not a compliant C compiler, and if the C compiler is not compliant,then it might do anything, but it's no longer C. A compliant compiler would have to provife software 32-bit  arithmetic. It's not hard to do. gcc implements 64-bit arithmetic on machines with only 32 bit ALUs. The standard is very clear about the minimum size of long.

Comment: @DanielV according to the standard long must be at least 32 bits