# How does logical operators in C differ from actual logical operations?

Tags: c, logical-operators

I have the following code snippets, and was somewhat confused by the output, based on my knowledge of how logical operators work. From what I know(based on truth tables in electronics),

1. For logical `AND`, `TRUE` and `TRUE` gives a value of `TRUE` and all other combinations of the truth table gives `FALSE`.
2. For logical `OR`, only `FALSE` and `FALSE` gives a value of `FALSE`. While all other combinations of the truth table gives `TRUE`.

Based on this knowledge, this first code snippet-

```
void main( )
{
int i = -1, j = 1, k ,l ;
k = i && j ;
l = i || j ;
printf ( "%d %d\n", i, j ) ;
printf("%d %d", k,l);
}
```

gives the output-

```
-1 1
1 1
```

I am confused here because according to truth tables of logical AND and OR, the value of k should be -1. This comes from the fact that value of `i` is `-1`(which is `FALSE`) and `j` is `1`(which is `TRUE`), so `TRUE` `AND` `FALSE` should equal to `FALSE`, that is, `-1`.

However, since the output was 1 for both `k and l`, I'm thinking that C processes logical `AND` and `OR` based on only 1 and 0 where `1 would be TRUE` and `0 would be false`. According to this logic, any non-zero value would be TRUE, so even `-1` would be `TRUE`.

In that case, `k=i&&j` would mean `-1&&1`. Since -1 and 1 are both TRUE, so the expression `k= i&&j` evaluates to `TRUE`, ie, 1. Following the same logic, `l=i||j` also evaluates to `TRUE`.

Am I correct in thinking that the second approach is the correct way in which logical operators work in C?

My second question is about the next code snippet-

```
void main( )
{
int j = 4, k ;
k = !5 && j ;
printf ( "\nk = %d", k ) ;
}
```

which produces the output `k=0`

This has really got me stumped, because I can't figure out how a Logical `NOT` works within a Logical `AND` operator. Here `j` is `4`, but what is the value of `k`, and how does this compare with `j`? I'm thinking since k is `not 5`, it could be `-5`? But in that case, `-5` and `4` both evaluate to `TRUE`, so the value of `k` should be `1`.

Please help.

Comment: your assumption is incorrect.  any non-zero value in C is true and zero is false, which includes -1 (treated as true)

Comment: Related to: [Do negative numbers return false in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840422/do-negative-numbers-return-false-in-c-c/18840464#18840464) and [Logical Operators in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16654155/1708801)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I correct in thinking that the second approach is the correct way in which logical operators work in C?

Yes. You are going right.
Remember that in C, a non-zero value is treated as `true`. `-1` is also `true` and it will be treated just like `1` for logical operations.
In

```
k = !5 && j ;
```

`!` is a [logical negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) operator. `!5` is `false` (there is a different operator `~` in C for Bit-wise negation). `k` will become `0`.

Comment: Understood, thanks a ton. However, I am still unclear about the second code snippet, where a logical NOT is used inside a logical AND. Could you please help about it?

Comment: Short-circuiting is only important for side-effects (like invoking UB in the skipped part of the expression). `~` is not negation but bitwise-complement, a bit-operation...

Comment: @Deduplicator;I think bitwise NOT, complement and negation are same thing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT

Comment: @Deduplicator; Why not ?

Comment: Well, when you add "bitwise", it does. Anyway, we are programmers, using exactly the same terms for three operations we can reasonably perform in the same context is ... somehow bad.

Comment: Why is a non-zero value treated as being true in C? A value is true in C if ANY of the bits in the variable are set. If NONE of the bits in the variable are set then it's just all zeroes: 000...000, which is 0, which is false.

Comment: @Galaxy; Do you know any value which is non zero and all of its bits are set to 0?

Comment: @haccks; Not in standard representation of integers in modern day computers, but of course the bits themselves could have any arbitrary meaning assigned to them.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your second question about (logical) negation:

```
int j = 4, k ;
k = !5 && j ;
```

Since any non-zero value is true, the NOT is negating a boolean value, not an int, so the next steps go like this:

```
k = !true && true
  = false && true
  = false
```