# when c++ return true / false if the data type is integer or double value

Tags: c++

we are migrating project from c++ to c#. Can any one let me know when
   c++ return true or false for integer or double datatype value.

```
int a=3; or int a=-3; ... etc

if(a) //it will return true or false
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: A non-zero bit pattern evaluates to true.

Comment: @saadtaame actually the condition is that it is true if `a != 0` is true, regardless of bit-pattern

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do negative numbers return false in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840422/do-negative-numbers-return-false-in-c-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns `false` for `0` and `true` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

If the variable is non-zero then it's return true

```
int a = 3; //or any negetive number like a = -3

if(a){
//This part will execute
}
else
{

}
```

2nd part:

```
int a = 0;
if(a){

}
else
{
//this part will execute
}
```