# Ternary operator condition issue

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
  int count = 1;
  while (count <= 5)
  {
    cout<<(count % 2 ? "****" : "++++++++")<< endl;
    ++count;
  }
  system ("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I am unable to understand `count%2`, shouldn't the condition be `count%2==0`? If it is `count%2`, how does the compiler know whether it is true or false?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do negative numbers return false in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840422/do-negative-numbers-return-false-in-c-c)

Comment: read an introductory book or tutorial on C++. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, if the compiler expects a boolean expression and finds a numeric type, it considers 0 to be `false` and anything else to be `true`.  Consequently, `count%2` is equivalent to `count%2 != 0`: `true` if odd.

Answer (score 1):

All values except 0 will evaluate to true.

So your `"*****"` will only print if `count % 2` is not `0`. (`null` in Java... I'm sorry)

Comment: oh ok thats why i was getting confused its clear now

Answer (score 1):

All is simple. It is enough to read one time a book on C++ or the C++ Standard or its Draft.

From the C++ Standard (4.12 Boolean conversions)

> 1 **A prvalue of arithmetic**, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or
>   pointer to member type **can be converted to a prvalue of type bool**.
>   **A zero value**, null pointer value, or null member pointer value **is converted to false**; **any other value is converted to true**. For direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can
>   be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

Thus if expression `count % 2` is not equal to zero (the reminder is equal to 1) then this expression is converted to `true`. Otherwise to `false`.

Of course instead of expression `count % 2` used in the condition you may write `count % 2 != 0`. However as the quote from the Standard says it is enough to write simply `count % 2` and this expression will be converted to an expression of type bool in the condition.

Comment: You'll need a lot more standard quotes than this if you want to explain this "simple" question using the standard. To start with, what's a "prvalue"? What's an "arithmetic type"? Your quote says that a "prvalue" of "arithmetic type" can be converted to bool, which rule in the standard says that the conversion will actually take place here?

Comment: @T.C.  For initial understanding it is enough to read this one quote. It is always better to see the source than to read of a description of the same i n other words.