# what is the result using operator "? :" for int value

Tags: c

Can you tell me what is the value of x in below code and explain the reasons?
I thought x should be be 8, but the result show it is 2...

```
int x=3;
x = 4? 2: 8;
```

Comment: Why do you think 8?  That is wrong, as you've found out.

Comment: You tell us why you thought x would be 8!

Comment: What is this operator "q" that you mention in the title? It is not mentioned in the body of the question.

Comment: 2 is the correct answer. Because zero(0) and negative value work as false and all positive value work as true.

check answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18840449/4813631

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do negative numbers return false in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840422/do-negative-numbers-return-false-in-c-c)

Comment: @AvanishKumar since when do negative numbers evaluate to `FALSE`? Negative means non-zero which evaluates to `TRUE`.

Comment: @AvanishKumar did you read the answer you mentioned? zeroes are false, everything else is true.

Comment: 'q' and '?' are at opposite ends of the keyboard.  Do you have your KB upside down?  :)

Comment: @Gerhardh and Jean-Baptiste, I am saying 0 and all negative number is the false and positive number is true. For example, I have a number -2 it means false and if I have 2 it means true.

In Short
>0 - 'true'
<=0 - 'false'

Comment: @AvanishKumar yes, understodd. But this is wrong! Negative numbers evaluate to `TRUE`. 0 is `FALSE`, everything else is `TRUE`. The answer you linked above tells you the same: Negative means `TRUE`

Comment: @Gerhardh Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is returning output 2 because your condition is true as you are checking for 4 which is always true in second line of code. If you want result as 8: Then write code as below:

```
int x=3;
x = x==4? 2: 8;
```

it will return 8 as condition is false because value of x is 3 and you are checking it against 4.

Answer (score 2):

This: `?:` is the ternary operator. Here's the syntax: `(condition) ? (if_true) : (if_false)`. What this means is that, this expression will return `if_true` if `condition` is true, else `if_false` will be returned.

So, in your case, the `condition` is `4` which is always true (because not all of the bits are `0` if you represent `4` in binary), hence the `if_true` part is returned. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C) as well.