# C remainder/modulo operator definition for positive arguments

Tags: c, division, modulo, integer-division

I found a function in a program I am supposed to fix that has a `mod` function defined:

```
int mod(int a, int b)
{
  int i = a%b;
  if(i<0) i+=b;
  return i;
}
```

I was told that `a` and `b` will always be positive by the way...

Huh? `if(i<0)`?

The argument is, [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

> the result of the modulo operation is an equivalence class, and any member of the class may be chosen as representative

And only as an afterthought

> ...; however, the usual representative is the least positive residue, the smallest nonnegative integer that belongs to that class, i.e. the remainder of the Euclidean division. However, other conventions are possible.

That means that `6 % 7` could return `6` (so far so good), but also `-1`. Hrm... really? (Lets ignore the fact that the presented implementation does not handle all cases.)

I know that it is mathematically true that the modulo operation is like this. But then someone else told me that the C `%` does in fact "not implement the modulo operator but the remainder".

So, how does C define the `%` operator?

In the C-Draft I only find

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the
>   second; the result of the % operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of
>   the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined.

Does this mean, that `6 % 7` is always `6`? Or can it be `-1`, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forever:

- `a == (a/b)*b + a%b`
- `abs(a%b) < abs(b)`
- if `a` and `b` are positive, `a % b` is positive.

Since C99,

- `a/b == trunc(a/b)`
- `a%b` is either `0` or has the sign of `a`.

Thinking that `6 % 7` could be `-1` is probably due to missing the fact that the result for `a` and `b` positive has always been guaranteed and missing the change in C99.

Answer (score 5):

According to the standard:

> When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the
>   algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded. If the quotient
>   a/b is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`.
>   [ISO/IEC 9899:2011: 6.5.5]

This means that the sign of `a` is preserved in the modulo.

```
 17 %  3  ->  2
 17 % -3  ->  2
-17 %  3  -> -2
-17 % -3  -> -2
```

---

So no, `6%7` cannot be `-1` because the reminder has to have the same sign of the dividend.

Comment: I did not ask about the sign

Comment: But it answers your question. It cannot be `-1` cause `6` is positive.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean, that 6 % 7 is always 6? Or can it be -1, too?

According to [this documention](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic):

> Remainder
>
> The binary operator % yields the remainder of the division
>   of the first operand by the second (after usual arithmetic
>   conversions).
>
> [...]
>
> when the type after usual arithmetic conversions is an integer type,
>   the result is the algebraic quotient (not a fraction), rounded in
>   implementation-defined direction (until C99)truncated towards zero
>   (since C99)

So `6 / 7` will be `0`, and `6 % 7` will be `6 - 0`, which is `6`.

The claim about modulo operations and equivalence classes is interesting, that's not how it works in C (and most other programming languages).

Besides, even if that were the case, wouldn't `-8` be in the same equivalence class? Then `if(i<0) i+=b;` wouldn't solve the problem.

> But then someone else told me that the C % does in fact "not implement
>   the modulo operator but the remainder".

Good point. In the documentation that I linked, it is called the "Remainder".

Comment: Indeed, you would need something equivalent to: `while(i<0) i+=b`

Comment: thanks, I have the same interpretation. and my comment "Lets ignore..." was exactly about your last sentence.

Comment: The documentation you link to is wrong. The C89 standard section 6.3.5 specifies "When integers are divided and the division is inexact, if both operands are positive the result of the / operator is the largest integer less than the algebraic quotient and the result of the % operator is positive."

Comment: The rounding of `/` and sign of `%` is only impl-defined (pre C99) if one or both operands are negative: "... If either operand is negative, whether the result of the / operator is the largest integer less than or equal to the algebraic quotient or the smallest integer greater than or equal to the algebraic quotient is implementation-defined, as is the sign of the result of the % operator. If the quotient a/b is representable, the expression (a/b) *b + a%b shall equal a. "

Comment: @PaulHankin thanks! That's more credible than the documentation. Do you have a link to this so I can add it to the answer?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three different ways of defining the division and remainder algorithms when one number or the other might be negative.  (See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) -- and particularly the [nice picture there](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Divmod.svg) -- for more details.)

But if you know you're dividing a positive number by a positive number, there's no ambiguity whatsoever.  All three definitions of division and remainder say that if you're dividing a positive number by a positive number, you get a positive quotient and a positive remainder.

Of the three options there, C uses the one called "truncating division".  But, again, for positive numbers, it doesn't make any difference.  (Once upon a time, it was up to the compiler whether it used truncating or "Euclidean" division, but things settled down on just the one definition, several revisions of the C Standard ago.)

> Does this mean, that `6 % 7` is always `6`? Or can it be `-1`, too?

Yes, `6 % 7` is always 6 (in C, and under any of the three definitions).

See also [this epic, related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224638/do-i-need-to-explicitly-handle-negative-numbers-or-zero-when-summing-squared-dig/58225192#58225192).